# how to prevent recyclerView auto scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView with chat message and open it will scroll to the latest position,but i update item's height in onBindViewHolder and recyclerView will auto scroll to incorrect position,how to pin item position after update item's height?

Answer (score 1):

into getMessages method add this below code

```
 layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(messagesRecycler, null, chatAdapter.getItemCount());
 chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want scroll to last item use `lm.setStackFromEnd(true);`

use below code:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
```

Comment: Great! But the item views will show from the bottom when there're no enough data in one screen and how to fix that?

Comment: @hongyannick I don't understand your purpose. I think your application gets data from a server. so, when got it, add them to recycle view.

Comment: emm..for example, after setStackFromEnd(true), there is only one data,it will show in the bottom of screen ,how could show in the top of screen?